# How do I access google javascript APIs in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, google-api, nativescript

For example I would like to access the Google Tasks API here. Probably I have to include the library in https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth . The problem is how to include this library in NativeScript files so I can use it? Or I can only use this library in things like PhoneGap and have to develop my own plugin on Android for this one? Or I have to use native APIs to do this in android?